# Change csv output from one column to multiple in html

Tags: html, csv

I have tried to find an answer but am not finding what I am looking for. I am using hostinger to host my website and using their built in design software. Their csv output creates a csv file with all parameters in one column instead of each parameter in its own column. I believe programming is in html and I don’t have access to base code but I can add to the “header” of the code with custom code. Does anyone know what will help me to solve my issue?

I haven’t tried anything yet as I’m not very familiar with html and Hostingers support team told me to look here as they specialize in hosting and support of that, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

are you using their Website builder and a pre-designed templates ?
if you think the problem come from website template, you can delete that section and use custom html code

https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/6475646-website-builder-how-to-customize-a-website-template#h_ed99b23b6a

There are two ways to add HTML code to your website, and it depends on the type of code you want to add.

If the code needs to be added to the  part of your website's source code, use the Custom code field in your website's integration settings.

If the code needs to be added to the  part of your website's source code, use the Embed code element.

Comment: My problem is that I don’t know what code to add in order to make the csv output how I want. And yes, I am using their website builder

Comment: or maybe the problem is in your excel setting..
maybe this video can help.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n57Z7UUY2Eo